# SQL select count with multiple cases

Tags: sql, aggregate-functions

I want a column where I count transactions where itemtype contains either one of two specified values or location contains one of two specified values.
The first two columns (itemtype and location) gives correct figures, but the third seems to count all transactions, irrespective of itemtype or location.
What am I doing wrong?

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN itemtype IN ('BARNTAL','STORSTIL') THEN 1 END) 'itemtype',
  COUNT(CASE WHEN location IN ('Lattlast','Appelhyllan') THEN 1 END) 'location',
  COUNT(CASE WHEN itemtype IN ('BARNTAL','STORSTIL') THEN 1 
             WHEN location IN ('Lattlast','Appelhyllan') THEN 1  
             ELSE 0
        END) 'total'  
FROM statistics
```

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: Hi there, which DBMS are you using (e.g. SQL Server, MySQL etc.)

Comment: Why cant you match location and itemtype in where clause

Comment: @Klas Just change the ELSE 0 to ELSE NULL or remove it as ELSE NULL is already implied.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`COUNT` counts not null values which means it also "counts" the `0` from the `ELSE` part. Remove the ELSE part altogether:

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN itemtype IN ('BARNTAL','STORSTIL') THEN 1 END) 'itemtype',
  COUNT(CASE WHEN location IN ('Lattlast','Appelhyllan') THEN 1 END) 'location',
  COUNT(CASE WHEN itemtype IN ('BARNTAL','STORSTIL') THEN 1 
             WHEN location IN ('Lattlast','Appelhyllan') THEN 1
        END) 'total'  
FROM statistics
```

Answer (score 1):

For last one you can use `SUM` instead of `COUNT` like below -

```
SELECT 
  COUNT(CASE WHEN itemtype IN ('BARNTAL','STORSTIL') THEN 1 END) 'itemtype',
  COUNT(CASE WHEN location IN ('Lattlast','Appelhyllan') THEN 1 END) 'location',
  sum(CASE WHEN itemtype IN ('BARNTAL','STORSTIL') THEN 1 
  WHEN location IN ('Lattlast','Appelhyllan') THEN 1  
 END) 'total'  

FROM statistics
```

Comment: An alternative would have been to change the ELSE 0 to ELSE NULL in the original COUNT version. Or remove it as ELSE NULL is already implied. :)

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to add `ELSE` part :

```
SELECT COUNT(CASE WHEN itemtype IN ('BARNTAL','STORSTIL') THEN 1 END) AS itemtype,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN location IN ('Lattlast','Appelhyllan') THEN 1 END) AS location,
       COUNT(CASE WHEN itemtype IN ('BARNTAL','STORSTIL') THEN 1 
                  WHEN location IN ('Lattlast','Appelhyllan') THEN 1  
             END) AS total
FROM statistics;
```

Answer (score 1):

I think, the third condition would be as below

```
SELECT
COUNT(CASE WHEN itemtype IN ('BARNTAL','STORSTIL') OR location IN ('Lattlast','Appelhyllan') THEN 1 END) AS total
FROM statistics;
```